# Module not found: Can't resolve 'swiper/css

Tags: reactjs, swiper.js

swiper version 7.0.6 problem: Module not found: Can't resolve 'swiper/css
any idea to solve this problem ?
here is my code :

```
import React from 'react'
import { Navigation, Pagination, Scrollbar, A11y } from 'swiper';
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react';
import 'swiper/css';
import 'swiper/css/navigation';
import 'swiper/css/pagination';
import 'swiper/css/scrollbar';

export default function Slider() {

    return (
      <Swiper
      // install Swiper modules
      modules={[Navigation, Pagination, Scrollbar, A11y]}
      spaceBetween={50}
      slidesPerView={3}
      navigation
      pagination={{ clickable: true }}
      scrollbar={{ draggable: true }}
      onSwiper={(swiper) => console.log(swiper)}
      onSlideChange={() => console.log('slide change')}
    >
      <SwiperSlide>Slide 1</SwiperSlide>
      <SwiperSlide>Slide 2</SwiperSlide>
      <SwiperSlide>Slide 3</SwiperSlide>
      <SwiperSlide>Slide 4</SwiperSlide>
    </Swiper>
    )
}
```

Know someone who can answer?

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with the new version you need to downgrade the swiper version.

Uninstall the previous version:

```
npm uninstall swiper
```

Install Swiperjs version 6.0.2:

```
npm install swiper@6.0.2
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case its work at - swiper version form **package.json**

```
"swiper": "^9.4.1",
```

inside your react component, import this -

```
import 'swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css';
```

Comment: The question is two years old 

Comment: Yes... You are right. I recently encountered an issue while trying to migrate/update the Swiper package. After facing some challenges, I managed to resolve it successfully. I believe sharing my solution here could be beneficial for others who might encounter a similar situation in the near future, like me.

Comment: You are right, thank you for sharing it!